# different outputs on different compiler

Tags: c++, c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [FAQ : Undefined Behavior and Sequence Points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176328/faq-undefined-behavior-and-sequence-points)

Different outputs on different compiler?
Is this true that certain statements can generate different outputs on different compilers. I have two compilers handy gcc and msvc expression edition. When I tried a code sample on both of them I was shocked to see different outputs on them.

This was the code sample.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
int variable_a = 100;
printf("%d %d", ++variable_a, variable_a++); return 0;
}
```

Output that I got on gcc was 102 100
On msvc I got 102 101.
Why such a difference?

Comment: "undefined behavior". http://stackoverflow.com/questions/949433/could-anyone-explain-these-undefined-behaviors-i-i-i-i-i-etc

Comment: The very fact that you bothered to type in the program suggests you had reason to suspect this, or were following a tutorial that should have proceeded to explain it - so why shocked?

Comment: i am in the learning stage and i like checking the outputs on more than one compilers. the outputs were different so thoght of asking here.

Comment: why is this undefined behavior KennyTm???

Comment: it's undefined simply because the language spec doesn't define unambiguously what a compiler can do there, hence there is no single correct output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You invoke undefined behaviour by incrementing `a` more than once. Any compiler would be within their rights to break into your house and beat you with a stick.

Comment: what is incrementing a more than once???

Comment: @Andrzej, +1 for use of "evocativeness"

Answer (score 1):

There are various subtle effects of this kind where the language is explicitly undefined. There's a lot of history behind why the language leaves these corners undefined. From the coder's point of view we need to avoid certain patterns such as the one you stumbled across.

[See this reference for some explanation](http://docs.hp.com/en/B3901-90007/ch05s09.html)